What do all branches of Mathematics have in common to be considered "Mathematics", or parts of the same field?
At some point in my life I think I've read what all branches of Mathematics had in common were numbers. But then I remembered a branch of the many Mathematics I had when I was an university student, and I didnt remember numbers in it. Then, I made a Google search to see about this, and I found this,
Could mathematics exist without numbers?.

Yes, and no. Yes, because we can do a lot of mathematics without
encountering the numbers, like topology, intrinsic geometry, or,
applicative algebra or combinatory algebra

So, what do all branches of Mathematics have in common to be considered "Mathematics"?

Do all forms need to have anything in common? What do all games have in common? Anything specific? (You also don't want to hear: "They are all developed by humans".)
The "dot dot dot" in @MauroALLEGRANZA comment is really what they all have in common :) (Also, "abstract objects" is a contentious term...)

@mudskipper I guess all games have a winner loser idea? And when something very ungamely goes that-a-way it often gets the word "game" eg. game theory, wargames

@Rushi - Not all games are played with the goal of "winning". (Even if this goal exists, it's usually not what makes a game fun to play.) Patience is a card game - is there a winner? Some multiplayer games are not zero-sum. We can formalize "game" in game theory (just like we can formalize math in hierarchies of theories) - but that is done for a particular purpose: we impose certain rules - so, in way, we change the game - it still doesn't give you a "common essence" of all.

@Rushi I feel like the definition of game is very akin to your "what you claim is universal to religion is actually very narrow to specific branches of Christianity"--it's easy to accidentally claim something is essential to games when it doesn't encompass the entirety of 'things that are games'. You might look at tag, hangman, RPGs, 'playing house', or Minecraft as games that don't get described well by 'winner/loser idea'

Math is essentially Platonism reified

@MauroALLEGRANZA So do religions. Maybe we need to add some notion of rigour to our abstractions.

@mudskipper Aren't all games defined by simple "willingly pretending"?

"Mathematics is what can be derived from Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory". That would be a nice, slick definition. But there are exceptions in research-level mathematics

@viuser so, what do those things have in common?

Many of the given answers assert that the axiomatic approach is part of the definition of mathematics. This is surely wrong. The axiomatic method was famously promulgated by Euclid, who was not active until approx. the 3rd century BC. People did arithmetic and geometry before the 3rd century BC, for example, Socrates' discussion with a slave, in the "Meno" dialogue, of the lengths and areas of figures drawn in the sand. Their reasoning was not grounded in any explicit axioms or rules of inference. Would you claim that Socrates and the slave, in the "Meno", were not doing mathematics?

@ScottRowe this is above my pay grade. Any math that I know (and probably you know) is derivable from ZF set theory (with Axiom of Choice): algebra, number theory, numerical analysis, probability theory, etc. But I heard that certain very advanced, research-level pure mathematics cannot be derived by ZFC and uses additional axioms, like the large cardinal axiom.

Math is independent of the properties of our universe.

@viuser https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1924/what-are-some-reasonable-sounding-statements-that-are-independent-of-zfc

@mudskipper Huizinga identified common traits of playing (probably almost but not quite congruent with "games") in his seminal Homo Ludens.

somewhat related to defining the boundaries of mathematics might be What does "most of mathematics" mean?

This seems like the wrong place for this question

@Karl "If there is a ‘platonic world’  of mathematical facts, what does it contain precisely? ... if it is too large, it is uninteresting, because the value is in the selection, not in the totality; if it is smaller and interesting, it is not independent of us. Both alternatives challenge mathematical platonism. ... the universality of our mathematics may be a prejudice and illustrate contingent aspects of classical geometry, arithmetic and linear algebra, ... "--Carlo Rovelli--Michelangelo’s stone: an argument against platonism in mathematics

@SimonCrase A world of mathematical facts is just plain empty, and hard to distinguish from one that doesn't exist. Basing an argument on is an exercise in futility.

@Karl I'm not sure what you are trying to say here, but possibly you aren't either.

Instead of asking what all branches of mathematics have in common, I'd look at that as: how can I distinguish a mathematical text (proof, argument, construction) from a non-mathematical one. I believe two things at least do jump out:

all proofs need to be deductive proofs (or reducible to deductive proofs)
the most important concept seems to be equivalence (in all its various forms); the proofs are always somehow about (abstract) equivalence relations

It's not at all trivial to really explain further what each of those points mean, so, I'm not sure if positing them goes beyond the "twittering of baby birds" (Zhuangzi).
Point (1) implies that we don't care about empirical facts; we don't need to do any empirical measurements or experiments. Paper and pen should (in principle) suffice.
Point (2) is perhaps most clear in actual equations and calculations.
Exactly what those "abstract" objects (equivalence relations in all their forms) are is a very contentious question where philosophers and mathematicians cannot seem to find any agreement on (the debate between intuitionists and realists, debates about finitary concepts).

UPDATE
See comments by @JD and @JKusin below. They make valid critical points showing that this answer is (at the very least) not the whole story. In a Wittgensteinian perspective you might say that all branches of mathematics share a "family resemblance" -- similar to how people in the same family are "all alike". So, two branches might "have the same nose" (deal with numbers and especially primes), while another two might have "the same eye color" (deal with spatial relations for instance). Unfortunately we don't know what the DNA of mathematics would look like... (at least I don't).
I'm also tempted to say that what's common in all math is "seeing analogies", "seeing how this is like that" -- but then all pattern recognition is a form of mathematics, so this doesn't seem very informative.
One thing that does seem relevant, and that I forgot to mention, is that in math we try -- as much as possible -- to treat (or pretend to treat) the abstractions as totally concrete, determinate objects. Hao Wang once made a comment like this (paraphrasing from memory, I wasn't able to find back the reference yet):

After all, mathematical objects are in a way more directly given to our understanding than perceived objects.


UPDATE on the UPDATE
It occurred to me that if all arts and sciences are like games, then mathematics might be characterized as the game that combines the maximum amount of playfulness (including establishing or changing rules in inventive, surprising, and "arbitrary" ways) with the maximum amount of rigor (run the algorithm, the "mechanical" procedure, the proof, or just "see it").

hmmm, does that work in Arithmetic? Is there a deductive demonstration for 2+2= 4 or it just has an empiric demonstration? . I'm seeing right now a mathematician attempting a deductive demonstration in Youtube that 2+2 = 4 and some users pointing some errors

+1 But, sounds quite prejudiced against mathematical modeling which is rather inductive in nature. Maybe you should concede Familienähnlichkeit as an organizing principle for definition.

Is the way the 4-color theorem was proved deductive or reducible to deductive? Was early math deductive? I think the answer is no in both cases.

@Pablo Using the Peano axioms, we have: Let 1 = S(0), 2 = S(1), 3 = S(2), 4 = S(3).  2+1 = 2 + S(0) = S(2+0) = S(2).  2+2 = 2 + S(1) = S(2+1) = S(S(2)) = 4

@JKusin - I do think everything has to be reducible. Also, Euclides was clearly deductive. But ... I was just wondering - what about purely visual proofs. Those also need to be reducible, I'd say, but still there is nothing wrong with them as proofs. So, (1) is kind of misleading... In my mind "deduction" and "algorithm" are also analogous...

@JKusin - With computer-generated proofs we're getting into uncharted territory, imo. If a  proof is not digested (and understood) by any humans in any way, is it still a mathematical proof? Is "a proof in principle" a proof? -- But why single out computers as in special need to be doubted?(!) Doesn't this question also reflects back on mathematicians?

My +1 is for the last para. I am reasonably convinced that Plato would have strenuously rejected that "Platonism" is about "abstract objects".  After all for Plato the real world was the Platonic world (to be fair he called it the intelligible world) and the world we nowadays call real he would call shadows of the real. [There was a comment here a few months ago to this effect; viz. that somebody remembers his philosophy teacher saying that Plato is grossly misunderstood/misrepresented as to promulgating "abstractions"]

I read a blog post recently by Stephen Wolfram related to defining the 'DNA' of mathematics. He has some really interesting ideas about the topology of what is easily discoverable.

@Rushi ha ha, next time someone says I am speaking in abstractions I'll say, "No, I'm talking about the real world, not that shadow world you live in." And he'll whack me with his slipper like Tilopa and say, "real this". (yes, completely backward, unforgivable)

@aantia - I believe I found Wolfram's post (https://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/foundations-mathematics-mathematica/) When he says "transformation rule" I say "equivalence relation". Wolfram's study of cellular automata should get much more attention of philosophers. Especially when combined with the notion of "emergent computation" (see for instance Melanie Mitchell's beautiful study of emergent computation in cellular automata runs). All of this is also very accessible even if you don't have an advanced degree in CS or math (though some CS background helps).

Aren't there inductive proofs as well (most obviously, the aptly named complete induction?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - The way I see it is that those proofs follow the principle of induction as proof schema. But this is similar to following for instance the schema of modus ponens in an old syllogism, or following another logical derivation rule. So, I think, you'd still call this a deductive proof. I think ultimately all mathematical (or logical) proofs are by analogy to certain schemata (derivation rules). The analogy itself can never be spelled out (in the proof). The question is then just: how do you justify the schemata (and express the analogy itself).

@mudskipper proofs by humans are multiply-checked by other humans. Proofs by computer ought to be multiply-checked by other computer programs constructed independently. Ideally, at least one of them ought to have a formal proof of correctness (though it is  still subject to the underlying hardware functioning correctly). I think the trouble is that there aren't many symbolic algebra packages and they may have more common elements than we might like.

(Note I'm disregarding the interesting case of purely visual proofs in geometry - which can be beautiful and very important for education, imo. But those proofs can perhaps also not be "purely" visual, since they seem to require some pointers -- verbal or otherwise: "this is ..., then that is ...")

@nigel222 - Indeed. -- But is this (the social embedding of math, the psychological need to double-check versus the pyschological revelation of certainty or "seeing" "this is it!"; the need of social validation) ever considered/studied in philosophy of math? We don't want "psychologism". If so, how can it be justified to ask to double-check a (candidate) proof :)

@mudskipper Justified, because people are human and make mistakes, even at the highest level. So proofs are checked, and quite often found wanting. Sometimes they are easily corrected, sometimes that involves very significant extra work, and occasionally the claimed "proof" isn't repairable. F.ex. Wiles's proof of the modularity theorem took two years to repair after a flaw was found in the version initially presented.

I don't think equivalence relation is a necessary criteria for mathematics - for example, you can have a partial order

@ajd138 - It's true, a partial order is not an equivalence relation in the strict sense of the word. But I'm trying to suggest a wider sense. Sort of where "transformation rule" and "equivalence relation" are the same kind of thing. A graph or a string is also not an equivalence relation - but anytime we're going to do something interesting with them, I think those kind of relations are what we're looking at or searching for (or using). Anyway, you definitely need to read what I wrote with a grain of salt (as noted in the "update" too).

Mathematical formalism gives an easy definition of the field. For example, Haskell Curry defined mathematics as the "science of formal systems". From this perspective, it's easy to test if a given pursuit is indeed mathematical: are you starting from a set of axioms and inference rules and studying their consequences? Then you are doing mathematics.
Now you may find this definition disappointing for number of reasons! To get you started:

Level of formalism. This definition certainly covers the works of Euclid, Russel, and mathlib4. But for thousands of working mathematicians, before and after the development of axiomatic set theory, their proofs do not follow the structure prescribed by any fixed formal system. The usual hope, to use a computer science metaphor, is that informal proofs should "compile down" to formal proofs with relative ease. However, the significant gap between the logician's and the working mathematician's notion of "proof" may give you pause.
Choice of "interesting" theorems. With relative ease, I could write a computer program that enumerates all the provable theorems of a set of axioms in order of increasing length of the shortest proof. If given sufficient time and space, the program would eventually print any provable theorem. Of course, most of the theorems would be "boring" from the perspective of, well, anyone! A major part of mathematics is interpretation, that is, developing abstractions and language to explain why theorems are interesting. (It's worth mentioning that this program is astronomically slow, so it would be of limited interest. Still, a useful thought experiment.)
Application to the real world. Mathematics appears to have applications to hard science, letting us make models that yield verifiable predications about the universe in many domains. Formalism does not capture this at all. It fails to reconcile the applicability of even grade-school mathematics to the real world.

Formalism defines mathematics as a game of "symbol-pushing", following simple rules to build proofs of theorems. This model elegantly captures the most rigorous sort of mathematical proof, and developing this point of view helped mathematics as whole develop. But as a philosophy, it fails to capture much of the real-world practice of mathematics.

The areas of math that interested me were applications, like Accounting, or surfaces of revolution.

@ScottRowe these are decent examples. You can certainly prove why the laws of calculus yield a given formula for a volume specified by a curve, with the proper definition of volume. However, formalism fails to explain why this mathematical definition of volume correspond to the physical one; why, say, the amount of water you can fit in the shape is equal to the result of the formula. But for simply carrying out the computation, it suffices.

@ScottRowe Now accounting (from my relatively naive perspective) seems purely formal! A symbol-pushing philosophy of mathematics fits quite nicely with calculating an interest rate, or following a set of rules to put the right number in box 6a.

When you said axiom, it came to my mind rules of games. I looked for the definition "a statement or proposition which is regarded as being established, accepted, or self-evidently true." and it seems to fit. (It continues in the next comment)

Then I looked in Google and found this written by a MA in pure Mathematics "What is the difference between Math and a game like chess? Both have some axioms, we use logic or rules to interact between objects (mathematical or of some game) and state new relationships between them.
There is no difference between a generic game and axiomatic Mathematics." https://thebeautyofmathematics.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-math-and-a-game-like-chess-Both-have-some-axioms-we-use-logic-or-rules-to-interact-betw

If you define Math as something starting from a set of axioms and inference rules and studying their consequences , won't that include board games?

@Pablo - Yes - you can study those games directly as mathematical structures. See for instance: https://math.berkeley.edu/~berlek/cgt/gobook.html
It's interesting to see how the theoretical/mathematical study has led to new insights about how best to play especially in endgames (some of those insight are also very easy to apply even if you're just an amateur player). (In "On Numbers and Games" John H. Conway also develops a theory of numbers defined as games. This is yet another surprising, funny twist. This book is also pretty readable to anyone without math degree.)

@Pablo - For a little child learning to count on its fingers, counting is also first of all a game... So, what's more "fundamental" -- games or numbers... :) I was thinking, if all arts (or sciences) are like games, then another way to single out math might be: the science (or art) that combines the max amount of playfulness (arbitrary rule changes) with the max amount of rigor (rule adherence).

@mudskipper where are the rules in art?

@Pablo - Oh, there are tons of rules in art! Look at music theory. Look at schools and traditions of painting. But the rules are constantly/slowly changing. There are also radically different ways to "reject all rules" (Jackson Pollock versus the "conceptual" anonymous dadaist smilingly-subversive art of "NOT ART")!

@mudskipper hmmm but you choose those rules.  In art I can grab a brush and do whatever I want, can't I? In Math I have to follow rules set by others, and if I pick a field I can't avoid certain rules. In Music you can follow some rules, ignore others, even randomly pressing keys and see if you come up with something you like

The question "what is art" has become a topic in art itself. Rejecting all tradition, however, is not a self-evidently clear stance - Jackson Pollock still follows his own 'rules' - it's inevitable. Also "NOT ART" follows a kind of dadaist rule book - very different. The cactus music of John Cage - is yet another way to got to the limit. Or free jazz (which seems totally dead now).  You can do a lot, and "randomly pressing keys" could be part of it, but you still need to somehow convince others to play along (and listen). Part of music is really that it needs to be expressive...

The main problem with all the extreme forms of music (or painting or poetry) - the total rejections of all tradition - is that those forms also become extremely tedious and predictable. (NOT ART is still funny because it's totally unpretentious and implicitly critical of capitalist society, but other forms of conceptual art are often just too "easy", merely decorative wallpaper.) If you see it like this, then you already admit that art needs tradition, which implies there will be certain rules -- even though you can change them a bit as you go along.

@Pablo - To see both rules + play and math + art merging, see: https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.849/fall10/lectures/

Hello. I like your answer! A small nitpick: I think there are many nice sets of axioms for which you cannot write a computer program like you describe in your second bullet point. Particularly my gripe is with "in order of increasing length" - assuming you mean "length of the theorems", any theory that admits such a computer program is recursive, but of course there are non-recursive theories (eg ZFC, PA, ...). I think you may have meant "in order of increasing length of the shortest proof of that theorem", which is possible (given nice enough axioms and a nice enough notion of length).


I think you may have meant "in order of increasing length of the shortest proof of that theorem"

Yes.

"Mathematics" is a topic which does not have well defined edges.  It is generally accepted that it operates on rather abstract concepts, such as using the number 5 rather than physical objects like a pile of 5 stones, and making abstract statements which are applicable to the physical objects as well (such as "5 is odd" which has the implication that "5 stones cannot be divided into two same-sized piles").
Mathematics is a linguistic term used to capture some human behaviors.  Like nearly every linguistic term in existence, it's fuzzy and built on history.  We tend to lump things in by some common behaviors:

If it deals with numbers, it's usually mathematics.
If it deals with deductive proofs, it's usually mathematics.
If it deals with exploring most abstract versions of things already in mathematics, it's usually mathematics.

And so forth.  But I think the fuzziness is well demonstrated by the fact that these boundaries change.  The definition of "what is a proof" has changed radically over time, and really the obsession with formal proofs as a fundamental element of mathematics picked up around the turn of the 20th century. Likewise, nowdays we consider logic to be a branch of mathematics, but for many centuries it was not.  Logic and reason were considered to be separate from mathematics until 1847, when George Boole wrote a paper on what is now called Boolean algebra.  This was an algebra, which was accepted to be a mathematical concept at the time, but it modeled the fundamentals of logic, showing that an entire discipline once thought of as separate could be approached mathematically, and thus bring to bear the powerful advances in mathematics that had been made.
So, in general, there's a fuzzy set of topics which are part of mathematics because, linguistically, we found it effective to treat them as such.  In addition to that, there's a class of topics which leverage those mathematics in a rather pure sense to make them more and more applicable to reality (applied mathematics) which eventually starts to intermix with engineering and science.  There's also a class of topics which abstract mathematics, distilling it further and further into it's essence.  Those eventually intermix with philosophy (hence posting the question here).
In the end, we create a sort of artificial hierarchy of purity, which is just absurd enough for XKCD to poke fun at it:


Deals with numbers...  accounting? Deals with deductive proofs... Aristotelian syllogisms? Exploring abstract versions... scholastic philosophy? As to the xkcd there is a key circularity here; see

@Rushi Agreed.  That's why "usually" was used several times. I also pointed out several places where the boundary got nebulous, although I admit I did not specifically list "accounting" as one of them.

Logic was swallowed up by math. Lots of fields are being swallowed by Engineering. I wonder which of the two fish is bigger?

I think xkcd is poking fun at all the others who claim to be "on top", not at the mathematicians. The mathematicians don't care if they are top or bottom. Either is fine. (In the middle perhaps also - but that's more for the poor 'plied ones.)

@ScottRowe - transfinite large cardinals are kind of a big fish, hard to gulp down... And infinitesimal surreal numbers are so tiny they also seem to swim right thru...

If you consider that all physical laws seem to be deducible from concepts of symmetry, maybe maths is on top after all.

When there's a directly applicable XKCD included, it's the right answer :-)

i would say that mathematics is basically the study of patterns within the constraints of certain formal systems of logic. Empirical data can provide or suggest the existence of particular patterns, but the social process of 'proof' is rooted in the extent to which people can be convinced that it's not possible, within a certain formal system of logic, for there to be any counterexample(s) to a specific pattern, a stronger condition than an empirically-based one in which something is asssumed  to be 'true' (in some sense) on the basis that "Well, we've not been able to find any counterexamples so far".

Mathematics concerns itself about idealized objects, their asserted properties (axioms) and the resulting deduced properties of such objects (lemmas and theorems). Deduced properties can found - initially - by any way but later need to be formalized logically for wider acceptance.
A branch of mathematics could be created without explicit use of numbers. Yet I doubt if such a branch of math would have much relevance/future to mathematics as a whole without any reference at all to such a fundamental concept as numbers.

Topology? Plane projective geometry? Category theory?

May not be using numbers explicitly in such fields but it's hard to see how such branches would evolve before their developers had followed corresponding developments with numbers. Otherwise where would the drive to do so - let alone their guiding intuitions - come from ?

I've been reading Mathematical Models: A Sketch for the Philosophy of Mathematics by Saunders Mac Lane, and I think he has something useful to say.
Mac Lane talks about the origin of various sorts of mathematics by starting with a selection of human activities, and abstracting aspects that turn out to be systematic and intrinsic. His examples include:

Counting (to arithmetic and number theory)
Measuring (to real numbers, calculus, analysis)
Shaping (to geometry and topology)
Grouping (to set theory and combinatorics)

Because we have abstracted key properties of the human activities, we can further the activities by rigorous manipulation, so we have the origin of proof.
Mac Lane also gives a diagram showing links between the abstractions. Why there should be such a thicket of links between abstractions from different human activities seems to be a mystery.
What do all branches of Mathematics have in common?
The commonality that you are seeking is abstraction from a human activity that interests you, trying to see whether your abstraction can be linked to existing abstractions, and applying rigorous deduction.
Two quotes from Mac Lane.

...mathematics is not the study of intangible Platonic worlds, but of tangible formal systems that have arisen from real human activities.

Mathematics consists of the discovery of successive stages of the formal structures underlying the world  and human activities in that world, with emphasis on those structures of broad applicability and those reflecting deeper aspects of the world.


The article includes useful and entertaining criticisms of schools such as Platonism, Bourbaki, the Grand Set Theoretic Foundation.


To recall some branches of mathematics: Set theory, algebra,
topology were the first books of Bourbaki in the middle of the 20th
century, for more information see
Bourbaki.
Later category theory focussed explicitly on mathematical structure:
Objects with certain structure and maps between these object which
keep this structure.

From the viewpoint of methodology all math has in common the method
of proposition and proof. Mature mathematical theories can be
axiomatized. The latter is often a tool which clarifies what a
mathematical theory can prove and what not.
A good example is the
final solution of Cantor’s continuum problem by Goedel and Cohen in
the 20th century, and the clarification of the parallel postulate in
the context of non-Euclidean geometry in the 19th century.

Can mathematics exist without numbers?
Yes, numbers are not
necessary for the mathematical theory of topology.  Until today
there is no Bourbaki volume on number theory.
Nevertheless numbers, notably integers and prime numbers, are one source of mathematics.
Again and again, old problems from number theory trigger the
development of new mathematical tools: From Gauss’ complex numbers
to Grothendieck’s scheme theory. Deligne’s proof of the Weil
conjectures and Wiles’ proof of Fermat's conjecture. The
still open Riemann conjecture has many implications in the theory of
prime numbers.



"Can mathematics exist without numbers?" I wonder if a more interesting question wouldn't be: can mathematics exist without quantity? It appears to me that quantity is the true essence of math, but this is just a hunch.

Classical logic.  Make definitions ("this is a Line."), make relations between these definitions ("These two lines compare equal.").
